# How do you define a function for partial in a controller to work in all of the views? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, partial-views

For example, I'm placing the partial `<%= render "layouts/location" %>` in views all over the site. I need a controller for the layout (I tried layouts_controller.rb ) so I could do

```
def _location
    @city = request.location.city
    @state = request.location.state
  end
```

The partial contains the code `<%= @city %>, <%= @state %>`

This is all effectively, supposed to display the city and state of the visitor on whatever page the partial is rendered on.

When I do this however, and push to heroku and migrate the database, I'm served the error:
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

So the question is, how do I define a function for a partial?

Comment: Is this partial used _a lot_? Because you could set a `before_filter` in `ApplicationController` that would set these variables for you. Even if your partial is being used, say, in 40% of your pages, it wouldn't be a big deal that on every request it took a few milliseconds to set those variables.

Comment: Yeh, like 70% of pages, would I before_filter then def location? or _location? or ?

Comment: I'll put an example as an answer.

Comment: `before_filter :location` after the classe definition and `def location ...`. On every page call, the location method will be called. Forget the _.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in a before filter in your application controller like so:

```
...
before_filter :location

def location
    @city = request.location.city
    @state = request.location.state
end
```

The name of the method needs to match the symbol in the `before_filter` call, but other than that, you can call the method whatever you want. The method must be in the ApplicationController class though.

**Clarification:** This will get called before every request in your application and set these two instance variables for you, so in every view, you will always and automatically have access to @city and @state.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like you can make a few improvements from the other solutions.

In ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :set_location, only: [:index, :show, :edit]

    def set_location
      @city = request.location.city
      @state = request.location.state
    end
end
```

It's likely that you don't need those variables for the create, update and destroy actions, so using `only: [...]` seems like a good idea. You can add other custom methods in there.
The main problem with that will be when your `create`action will fail, and you'll want to render the "edit" page. If you don't need those variables on the edit page, then everything's fine. Otherwise, you'll need to call `set_location` yourself:

```
def create
    @lala = Lala.new(...)
    @lala.save
    set_location if @lala.errors.any?
    respond_with @lala
end
```

Also, in the 30% of pages that don't need those variables, you can use `skip_before_filter`:

```
 class BlogsController < ApplicationController
    #assume you dont need those variables in your blog

    skip_before_filter :set_location # you can also use only: [:index, ...] here
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [cells](http://cells.rubyforge.org/). It is an awesome, but rather unknown gem that allows you to structure your application in "cells". It might be just what you need.